# Namespace "manufacturing" when I include <algorithm>

Tags: c++, namespaces, g++

I have a namespace problem that is driving me bat-sh*t crazy.  There is a namespace called "Utility" written by another programmer here that I am using in some of my code.  One file gives me nothing but problems.  This file includes < algorithm > and I must have it.  I've tried all kinds of rearranging and other random stuff to try and get rid of it.  I cannot for the life of me figure out why stl_algo.h has this problem.

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h: In function ‘void std::random_shuffle(_RAIter, _RAIter)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:5152:40: error: ‘std::Utility’ has not been declared
```

Comment: Please try to construct an artificial test case (by cutting your program down) containing the *smallest possible amount of code* that *still demonstrates the problem*, and then post that here.  Right now we don't have nearly enough information to help you.

Comment: It looks like some sort of macro problem.

Comment: OK, the offending line seems to be `std::iter_swap(__i, __first + (std::rand() % ((__i - __first) + 1)));`. My guess is someone `#define`'d `rand` to be `Utility::rand` or something similar.

Comment: Yep, [repro](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/fpmHj0wYCphTuooT).

Comment: Can you change all call sites to use the fully qualified Utility::rand ? Get rid of the define because it will continue to drive you and others crazy.

Comment: I don't think this is a useful question (anymore). Any sane programmer knows not to `#define` random symbols, let alone those defined in standard headers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can [reproduce the exact error, line numbers, positions and all](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/iO8agv8cze0dtyuy), with

```
#include <cstdlib>
#define rand Utility::rand
#include <algorithm>
```

which produces

```
In file included from /usr/local/gcc-4.6.4/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.4/../../../../include/c++/4.6.4/algorithm:63:0,
                 from prog.cc:3:
/usr/local/gcc-4.6.4/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.4/../../../../include/c++/4.6.4/bits/stl_algo.h: In function 'void std::random_shuffle(_RAIter, _RAIter)':
/usr/local/gcc-4.6.4/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.4/../../../../include/c++/4.6.4/bits/stl_algo.h:5152:40: error: 'std::Utility' has not been declared
```

So go through your headers and look for something `#define`'ing `rand`. Smack the person responsible for this horrendous hack, hard, and then delete the `#define`.

Comment: I've just gotten into work this morning so have only had a few moments to look around, but indeed there seems to be some #undef of rand and redefining of the term.  I'll chastise later but see if I can work around the problem in the interim.  Thanks a bunch!  That's quite a lot of hacking to get the exact message and failure point.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a macro defined with name `rand` or `iter_swap` prior to including `<algorithm>`.

To workaround, try including `<algorithm>` before including other headers or do:

```
#undef rand
#undef iter_swap
#include <algorithm>
```